# Calculating change in independent variables based on change in Y and beta coefficient

Tags: regression

it's been a while since I studied statistics and I would like to know if I can solve the following problem:

I have:

- % change in the Y (dependent variable)
- the beta coefficient linking Y and X

I do not have:

- values for X (independent variable) which is expressed in units (not %)

I would like to estimate the change in X based on the information I have - i.e. I know Y changed by -36% and I know the beta coefficient is 0.083 (or +8.3%). Is this possible?

My initial thoughts were to divide the % change in Y by the beta coefficient = -36% / +8.3%.

Many thanks.

Comment: Is this a linear model? Logistic?

Comment: Hi @user2974951 - it is a linear model.

Comment: In that case this looks OK.

Comment: Great, thank you.